# Extracting multiple rows from a matrix depending on ID given by a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

Suppose we have a matrix `m` with 3 columns and a vector `id` with an identification for the rows:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,4,6,7,7,
          2,2,2,4,4,5,8,9,9),ncol=3,byrow=T)

# m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    2
#[2,]    1    2    3
#[3,]    2    2    2
#[4,]    3    3    4
#[5,]    6    7    7
#[6,]    2    2    2
#[7,]    4    4    5
#[8,]    8    9    9

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,4,5)
```

What is the fastest way to extract the rows from `m` with `id`?

As a result I'd like to have a vector for each unique identifier in `id`. Something like:

```
##[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2
##[2] 1 2 3
##[3] 2 2 2
##[4] 3 3 4 4 4 5
##[5] 6 7 7 8 9 9
```

My rather poor solution is way too slow for my purposes:

```
pts_list <- list()
for (i in unique(id)){
  pts_list[[i]] <- as.vector(t(m[id==i,]))
}
pts_list
```

Here a little script to test the speed (this is really ugly...):

```
pts_list <- list()
m2 <- cbind(m,m,m,m)
m3 <- rbind(m2,m2,m2,m2,m2,m2,m2,m2,m2,m2)
m4 <- rbind(m3,m3,m3,m3,m3,m3,m3,m3,m3,m3)
m5 <- rbind(m4,m4,m4,m4,m4,m4,m4,m4,m4,m4)
m6 <- rbind(m5,m5,m5,m5,m5,m5,m5,m5,m5,m5)
id6 <- rep(1:8000,10)

system.time(
  for (i in unique(id6)){
    pts_list[[i]] <- as.vector(t(m6[id6==i,]))
  }
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  8.094   1.524   9.617
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the values order you could simply do

```
split(m, id)
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 1 2 2 2
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 2 2 2
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 3 4 3 4 4 5
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 6 8 7 9 7 9
```

If you do care, you could combine it with `lapply`

```
lapply(split(as.data.frame(m), id), function(x) c(t(x)))
# $`1`
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 2 2 2
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 3 3 4 4 4 5
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 6 7 7 8 9 9
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's lightning fast. For the sake of speed I'm happy to have my numbers juggled around. It seems like the first and the last number are still in place, which is all I really need.

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` should provide a little speed gain over `for`

```
> system.time(
     for (i in unique(id6)){
         pts_list[[i]] <- as.vector(t(m6[id6==i,]))
     }
 )
   user  system elapsed 
   4.74    0.67    5.45 

> system.time(
     pts_list <- lapply(unique(id6), function(x) as.vector(t(m6[id6==x,])))
  )
   user  system elapsed 
   3.92    0.66    4.65
```